# StackOverflowError Exception when calling to getInflater() in android

Tags: android

I get StackOverflowError Exception when calling to getInflater() method.I tried to call that method and pass it to another object to call View arg3=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lastrow_layout, null) method.So why this type of errors occur and how can I solve that?Or there any way to do same thing whithout passing inflater object?
This is error log.

```
  GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 9% free 2645K/2884K, paused 73ms, total 89ms
  threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Lcom/example/ikmantest2/MainActivity;.getInf later:L                                                                                          method requires 8+20+4=32 bytes, fp is 0x4364f318 (24 left)                                                                                             expanding stack end (0x4364f300 to 0x4364f000)                                                                                      Shrank stack (to 0x4364f300, curFrame is 0x43654ec4)                                                                                      Shutting down VM                                                                                              threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)                                                                              GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 5% free 3146K/3304K, paused 77ms+79ms, total 249ms
 09-07 08:40:57.719: D/dalvikvm(1155): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms         
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.StackOverflowError         atcom. example. ikmantest2. MainActivity.getInflater(MainActivity.java:253)
```

This is the code give error.(This with in Activity_Main.java)

```
       public LayoutInflater getInflater() {        
             return getInflater();
       }
```

And this Inflater object use in another class as this;

```
           View arg3=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lastrow_layout, null)
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you!

Comment: Here is the code above.

Comment: Is `inflater` in the second snippet `inflater = Activity_Main.getInflater()`. Post more code, it isn't possible to help you with this little information.

Comment: No, LayoutInflater getInflater() is a method of a interface name SetScreen .I implement that interface in Activity_Main.So in second snippet it like LayoutInflater inflater = screen.getInflater(); screen is type of SetScreen.Can you help?Or specify what type of code i must send?

Comment: Is the second snippet in a different `Activity` or is it just a simple class?

Comment: Simple class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: Man, please share your full code. I am tired asking every single code from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is calling itself, that's the reason of the stack overflow.

You probably want something like

```
public LayoutInflater getInflater() {       
    return (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Where `this` is a valid `Context`.

Comment: You are much wise.I got sense that simple thing with your answer now.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater mInflater;
View arg3 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lastrow_layout, null);
```

Try this. Hope it's work.